# Creating a XML document using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, csv

I have been searching the internet for a way to create an xml document from a CSV document using rails.  I was wondering if anyone knew how, or could point me in the direction, of how to create a new file and lines to it.  I already know how to parse the CSV file. I just need help on creating the new xml file, adding lines to it, and saving it all in a rails controller.

Any gems that will make this easier would be very much appreciated!

Edit:  I would like to create this file line by line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'builder'

file = File.new("path_to_file.xml", "w")

xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:target=>file, :indent => 2)

xml.instruct! :xml, :encoding => "UTF-8",  :version => "1.0"

xml.transformation do |transformation|
  transformation.info do |info|
    info.other_info '0'
  end
end
```

will create the xml

```
<transformation>
  <info>
    <other_info >0</other_info >
  </info>
</transformation>
```

For a csv, all you need is the header and data seperated by `,`